# Setting parent page controls visibility from Child user control page

Tags: asp.net, .net, updatepanel, parent-child

I have a parent page Page1 which has button1. Page1 has a usercontrol uc1. uc1 has an update panel inside which a grid grid1 is present. I am trying to set Page1.button1's visibility to false, depending on the row command event(there are some if conditions in the row command event) of uc1.grid1. I am setting Page1.button1's visibility in the following way:

Create a IsButton1Visible property in uc1. Set the property in UC1.Grid1.RowCommand to false, on page1 PreRender event, access IsButton1Visible and set Page1.button1 visibility.

Even though in quick watch Page1.button1 visibility is set to false at the line of assignment, when I see the UI, it is still visible. I don't know what I am doing wrong. Or the way that I am getting hold of button1 and its visibility is not correct.

In general can we set a Parent page's control's property from a user control during the user control event?

Comment: Your question is a little confusing. Are you sure you mean the `IsButton1Visible` property is part of the usercontrol?

Comment: Raise a custom event in your UserControl that your your page can handle. Then you can switch visibility there according to the event arguments or UserControl properties.

Comment: A better approach might be to have an event on your control to the effect of `UpdateParentButtonVisibility` and create an event arg that sets the desired visibility.  Your parent page can then subscribe to the event and handle it appropriately.

Comment: @freefaller Yes. IsButton1Visible Property of user control. The idea I thought was to set IsButton1Visible(bool) Property in the user control uc1 during the uc1.Grid1 Row Command event, and then access this property from Page1 in the Page1.prerender event and set Page1.button1.Visibile = uc1.IsButton1Visible. But setting visibility of Page1.button1 has no effect. I think I have misunderstood the way update panel works. Even though I set the property the Page1 is not refreshed at all. Am I clear in my explanation?

Comment: @SARAVAN Would it be safe to say that your button lives outside of your update panel?

Comment: @JTorres Your statement is very very perfect!! Thats correct.

Comment: If that is the case, you are either going to have refresh the entire page OR use javascript to hide the button.

Comment: @SARAVAN Added a new answer that provides a javascript solution so you can maintain your update panel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the event-driven model approach

Delegate/EventArgs code:

```
public class ButtonVisiblityEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public ButtonVisiblityEventArgs(bool visible)
    {
        this.Visiblity = visible;
    }

    public bool Visiblity { get; private set; }
}

public delegate void UpdateParentButtonVisibilityEventHandler(object sender, ButtonVisiblityEventArgs args);
```

User control code:

```
    public event UpdateParentButtonVisibilityEventHandler RaiseUpdateParentButtonVisibilityEvent;

    private void RequestParentButtonVisibilityChange(bool setVisible)
    {
        if (RaiseUpdateParentButtonVisibilityEvent != null)
        {
            RaiseUpdateParentButtonVisibilityEvent(this, new ButtonVisiblityEventArgs(setVisible));
        }
    }
```

And in your command handler, just call:

```
    RequestParentButtonVisibilityChange(false);
```

whenever you want to hide the button.  On your page:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.RaiseUpdateParentButtonVisibilityEvent += new UpdateParentButtonVisibilityEventHandler(uc_RaiseUpdatecurrentDisplayPanelRequestEvent);
    }

    private void uc_RaiseUpdatecurrentDisplayPanelRequestEvent(object sender, ButtonVisiblityEventArgs args)
    {
        button1.Visible = args.Visiblity;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Just wanted to know, if this will work in case of an event happening in the grid control which is inside an update panel in user control

Comment: This answer will NOT work if the grid is in an update panel and the button to update is outside of the update panel.  I've provided another answer that will work in that case.

Comment: This answer made me to think about how the update panel works. I am using the idea suggested in the answer above. Thanks for helping out.

Answer (score 0):

If the problem you are having is that your button lives outside of the update panel, you can do the following.  Page codebhind:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string hideScript = string.Format("function updateButtonVisibility( visibility ) {{ var button = $('#{0}'); if (visibility) {{ button.show(); }} else {{ button.hide(); }} }}", this.button1.ClientID);

        Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "updateButtonVisibility", hideScript, true);

    }
```

And in your user control command handler:

```
   bool shouldButtonBeVisible = false; //update this appropriately in your logic
   ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "upUpdateButtonVisibility", "updateButtonVisibility(" + shouldButtonBeVisible ? "true" : "false" + ");", true);
```

Please note that this creates a TIGHT dependency between your UC and the page.  It requires that any page that consumes this control has registered this script.  There are ways to get around this (such as setting a function script callback to call, detecting if that javascript function exists, etc), but this should at least get you moving.

If there is something specific on the page after your update panel finishes that you could key off, it might be better to register an end request handler

```
$(function() { Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(updatePanelEndRequestHandler); } );

function updatePanelEndRequestHandler() {
   var shouldBeVisible = $('.MyClassThatSaysIShouldntAllowMoreButtons').length > 0; //do some checking on the grid
   updateButtonVisibility(shouldBeVisible);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can put your user controls inside panels on your parent pages and change the visibility.

e.g.

```
   <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="pnlQuote">
        ...
    </asp:Panel>

    <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="pnlContact">
        <uc1:ContactForm runat="server" ID="ContactForm " />
    </asp:Panel>
```

From the child control you can make a button click event which does something like this

```
 protected void btnBackToQuote_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Panel pnlQuote = this.Parent.FindControl("pnlQuote") as Panel;
            Panel pnlContact = this.Parent.FindControl("pnlContact") as Panel;

            pnlQuote .Visible = true;
            pnlContact.Visible = false;
        }
```